# Trouble checking files out/in Team Foundation Build

Tags: tfsbuild

I am trying to build a variety of csproj files using tfsbuild and visual studio 2012. I have created a build definition with the proper processes to build three different csproj files. Each csproj file has prebuild and postbuild events, the majority being simple delete and copy commands. With just these steps the builds work great.
Now I want to add commands to have the files check out of tfs before building and check back in after the build. I've added the proper VS command-line commands to the prebuild and postbuild events

Checkout:

"$(DevEnvDir)tf" checkout /lock:none "$(Pathname)$(ConfigurationName)\$(TargetFileName)"

Checkin:

"$(DevEnvDir)tf" checkin "$(Pathname)$(ConfigurationName)\$(TargetName).*" /noprompt /force /comment:"Build check-in"

However now when I try to build I get an error returned that looks like this:

$/AiFramework/toolbox/Accelitec.Utility/Accelitec.Utility.csproj - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s), View Log File
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (1063): The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\tf" checkout /lock:none "\AiDevelopment\AiFramework\bin\Debug\Accelitec.Utility.dll"" exited with code 100.

There isn't much more information provided by the error report as to what is going wrong.
An interesting point, when I build the files locally and individually, even with the checkout/in commands in place, the files build and even do the proper checkout/in.

My thoughts (backed up with some fiddling with the command line on the team server) are that it has something to do with workspaces, specifically workspaces required to check out a file, but other than that I am lost with where to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you get away from post-build events, and instead, modify the workflow. At the very least, use MSBUILD and not the post-build events.

Answer (score 0):

> Also verify the workspaces.

I had the same problem some time ago. What happened was multiple map to the same destination in different workspaces.

Clean drop folder and request a new build with the following parameters:

```
/p:OverrideForceGet=true;OverrideSkipInitializeWorkspace=false
```